# Waiting for series of axios calls to return

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm writing a React application for submitting timesheets, and having an issue when trying to submit a bunch of entries at once. Each entry has to be submitted in a separate API call, so what I have so far looks like this. This is inside a redux Thunk if that helps as well.

```
var foo = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    timesheets.forEach(timeentry => {
        api_function = 'XXXXXX' // string for submitting 1 entry
  
        axios.post(url, api_function);
    }
})
```

The idea is that once all of these are posted, I can do another call to refresh the timesheet data I have to display for the frontend. The problem I'm running into, is that not all of the posts are posting properly, sometimes only 2-3 of them go through.

I have done some console logging to see that the forEach loop is running the correct amount of times, and that the api_function string is sending the correct data in each of those loops.

I am not sure the logic of which entries are sending properly and which are not, as its not always the first 2-3 that work, but seemingly chooses which ones go through at random.

If there is a better way to be doing this, that would also be greatly appreciated, to summarize, I'm looking for a way to call a series of POST api calls, wait for them all to be done, then make a get call to refresh that data

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Create an array of Promises and await them all, e.g. `await Promise.all([......])`. If you need more specific help than this can you [edit] the post to include better details and a more complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an `Promise.all()`

```
var foo = Promise.all(timesheets.map(timeentry => {
   api_function = "xxxx"
   return axios.post(url, api_function)
}))
```